# How to add a ...loading to my tabbed ajax script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tabs, loading

I used a flowplayer tutorial to make some ajax tabbed content but the it doesn't use any kind of a loading indication in between content load. How can I add that to this script? http://pastebin.com/PebcJspn

```
<script>
    $(function() {

        $(".feed-tabs ul").tabs("div.feeds > div", {

            effect: 'fade',

            onBeforeClick: function(event, i) {

                // get the pane to be opened
                var pane = this.getPanes().eq(i);

                // only load once. remove the if ( ... ){ } clause if you want the page to be loaded every time
                if (pane.is(":empty")) {

                    // load it with a page specified in the tab's href attribute
                    pane.load(this.getTabs().eq(i).attr("href"));
                }

            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Added the code in the post, no reason to go to another site for that small chunk of code.

Comment: Where do you want the loading message?

Comment: oh oops...I want it to appear at the top of div.feeds. I'd like to position it somewhere in the center of that section as thats where the  content loads into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try add an element with a loading gif before call the method `.load()` and it will be removed when `.load()` inserts the html result.

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $(".feed-tabs ul").tabs("div.feeds > div", {
      effect: 'fade',
      onBeforeClick: function(event, i) {
        // get the pane to be opened
        var pane = this.getPanes().eq(i);

        // only load once. remove the if ( ... ){ } clause if you want the page to be     loaded every time
        if (pane.is(":empty")) {
          //add this
          pane.append("<img src='http://mentalized.net/activity-indicators/indicators/ilcu/roller.gif'/>")
          // load it with a page specified in the tab's href attribute
          pane.load(this.getTabs().eq(i).attr("href"));
        }
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```